# Como saber quantos numeros de uma lista se repetem em outras?

Tags: python, lista

Tenho quatro listas com os respectivos valores:

```
 A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
 B = [1,2,3]
 C = [4,5,6] 
 D = [7,8,9,10]
```

Teria alguma função para comparar a lista A com as outras três listas e dizer quantos números da lista A se repetem com os da 3 listas seguintes?
Por exemplo: A lista A contém 3 números da lista B, lista A contem 3 números da lista C, lista A contem 4 números da lista D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A estrutura `set` possui a função `intersection`, que retorna a intersecção entre o `set` e outro elemento iterável, como uma lista. Podemos facilmente definir uma função que simplesmente transforma uma das listas num `set` e retorna o tamanho da intersecção (elementos comuns) entre uma lista e outra:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
B = [1, 2, 3, 5, 11]

def contagem_interseccao(a, b):
    s = set(a)
    return len(s.intersection(b))

print(contagem_interseccao(A, B))  # 4
```

Comment: @EduardoMarques imagina! Todos já fomos iniciantes. Fico feliz em poder ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode converter ambas as listas para um `set` para então usar o [operador de intersecção (`&`)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) para se calcular a quantidade de elementos em comum entre eles:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
B = [1, 2, 3, 5, 11]

n = len( set(A) & set(B) )

print( n )
```

Saída:

```
4
```